# g++ fails to resolve template function overload

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, language-lawyer, variadic-templates

With the following code g++ fails:

```cpp
template <typename X = int, typename T, typename ...R>
    inline void func(const T&, R...) {}

template <typename T>
    struct S {};

template <typename X = int, typename T, typename ...R>
    inline void func(const S<T>&, R...) {}

int main() {
    func(42);
    func(S<int>()); // OK
    func(S<int>(), 1); // NOK
    func<int>(S<int>(), 1); // NOK
}
```

with:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:13:21: error: call of overloaded 'func(S<int>, int)' is ambiguous
     func(S<int>(), 1); // NOK
                     ^
<source>:13:21: note: candidates are:
<source>:2:17: note: void func(const T&, R ...) [with X = int; T = S<int>; R = {int}]
     inline void func(const T&, R...) {}
                 ^
<source>:8:17: note: void func(const S<T>&, R ...) [with X = int; T = int; R = {int}]
     inline void func(const S<T>&, R...) {}
                 ^
<source>:14:26: error: call of overloaded 'func(S<int>, int)' is ambiguous
     func<int>(S<int>(), 1); // NOK
                          ^
...
```

Reproducible with gcc v4.8.1 and v9.1. Compiles with clang (v3.0.0 and v8.0.0), icc (v13.0.1 and v19.0.1), msvc (v19.14 and v19.20).
Is the code valid or is this a bug in gcc?

*EDIT: Thanks everyone, your feedback was helpful for me. FYI, [bug 90642](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90642) has been filed; looking forward for a definite answer.*

Comment: There is no partial specialization of function templates in C++. Only full specialization and overloading.

Comment: You don't specialize the function, you overload it. And the compiler can't distinguish between the two overloads for the arguments you pass.

Comment: Thanks, I meant gcc is failing to specialize. I understand what you mean, but then why func(S<int>()) is OK and func(S<int>(), 1) not?

Comment: fti clang compiles gcc does not, live:  https://godbolt.org/z/p1HsRC

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. If you remove the useless and inconsequential `typename X = int`, it compiles. There is no reason why one should be valid and the other should not.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. I think what you run into here is [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution), more specifically [partial ordering rules for template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading)

I quote:

> Informally "A is more specialized than B" means "A accepts fewer types than B".

I think the clang is correct to compile that and the resulution should take the second candiate

```
template <typename X = int, typename T, typename ...R>
    inline void func(const S<T>& t, R... p) {}
```

Because in case the first argument is not of type `S<T>`, it is no longer viable and thus more specialized.

Comment: do you think it's worth filling a bug?

Comment: I am not 100% sure either. I think its worth at least to get another opinion what the correct behavior is ;)

Comment: @oknenavin I think too that this is a bug. Maybe related to this one: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41958 but still a different one. The bug vanish without the defaulted template parameter.

Comment: @Oliv Thanks. I thought it's a bug from the beginning, but it's complex subject and I'm not sure. I found this while working on an evolution of existing code base (https://github.com/oknenavin/cxon), and unfortunately, this default template parameter is part of the interface.
I'm going to fill a bug, but I still wait for account (gcc/bugzilla).